# Less version of bootstrap 3.2.0?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need a Less/Sass version of Bootstrap version 3.2.0 for an old site - where can i get that?

I tried using the current version, but apparently it does not support the Jumbotron, and the Glyphicons..

Comment: https://bootstrapdocs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.2.0
 - Shows Changes and such

https://bootstrapdocs.com
All versions as released at that time.

This is the full release from 3.2.0

You can download the full source and the less is in there. Hope this helps!